# Easy way to modify progress bar in existing Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, progress-bar

I am using demo code which compresses all files in folder. However, it's progress bar displays not total progress, but progress for every file.

Is there any easy way to modify code so progress bar would display total progress and not progress for every single file?

```
procedure DoProgress(Sender: TObject; Position, Total: Integer);
procedure DoCompressFile(Sender: TObject; const Filename: string);
```

....

```
procedure TJvZLibMultipleMainForm.DoCompressFile(Sender:TObject;const Filename:string);
begin
  lblFilename.Caption := Filename;
  Update;
end;

    procedure TJvZLibMultipleMainForm.btnCompressClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  z : TJvZlibMultiple;
begin
  ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(edFilename.Text));
  z := TJvZlibMultiple.Create(nil);
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    lblFilename.Caption := '';
    pbProgress.Position := 0;
    z.OnProgress := DoProgress;
    z.OnCompressingFile := DoCompressFile;
    z.CompressDirectory(edSrcFolder.Text,true,edFilename.Text);
  finally
    z.Free;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
  pbProgress.Position := 0;
  lblFilename.Caption := 'Ready';
end;


procedure TJvZLibMultipleMainForm.DoProgress(Sender: TObject; Position, Total: Integer);
begin
  pbProgress.Max := Total;
  pbProgress.Position := Position;
  Update;
end;
```

Comment: Totally depends on the implementation of TJvZlibMultiple.CompressDirectory. Look at the source or the documentation and see if there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: Depending on how long each file takes, users might appreciate a double progress bar display - retain the one you see implemented here, and add a progress bar that shows overall progress by incrementing with each completed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or better yet, add up the size of the files to a total size and increment position by the number of bytes processed.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be counting the files in the directory with Findfirst and Findnext, then setting pbProgress.Max to that and then incrementing pcProgress.Position by 1 in DoCompressFile.