# Delphi XE2 .Z Unix compressed files library

Tags: delphi, zip

I need to manage .Z (Unix compressed) files, mainly dezip function.
What is the best library to do this ?
Prefere to avoid Dll (like 7z.dll).
Edit : Today I have a solution with JCL compression library interfaced to 7z.dll.
I just wanted to look for a more light & simple solution as I just need the '.Z' decopression function.

Comment: .Z files are read/written by ZLIB, which is written in C. Several parts of Delphi use it, and so binary `.obj` file versions (compiled using an old Borland C compiler) are included with delphi. You can statically link to it.  The Jedi JCL library shows how to use it its example folders, and the JVCL wraps the jedi JCL wrappers in component form, with TJvZLibMultiple. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450510/compress-all-files-but-skip-one

Comment: @WarrenP I yet tried JCL/JVCL but TJvZLibMultiple does'nt seems to recognize .Z and when I try JCL compress example it needs 7z Dll.

Comment: @Warren, .Z files are managed by the `compress` tool, which uses the *LZW* compression algorithm. Zlib handles .gz and .zip files with the *deflate* algorithm. The `gzip` tool, although classically an interface for Zlib, happens to be able to handle both compression formats, but Zlib itself is still just for deflate, not LZW.

Comment: Phil, maybe you can suck what you need out of Intraweb, which seems to include that stuff: http://www.atozed.com/IntraWeb/Blog/20120511.en.aspx  You can get a free download of version 9 here: http://www.atozed.com/IntraWeb/Download/IntraWeb9EnterpriseFree.EN.aspx

Comment: @Rob; Doesn't the Z extension connote explicitly the use of `deflate`? And GZ extension the use of LZW?

Comment: No, @Warren, it's the other way around. Deflate is LZ77 plus Huffman. Gzip is deflate plus headers and a checksum. LZW is LZ78 plus Welch and a (now expired) patent. Wikipedia and man pages tell the story. Therefore, the gzip stuff in Intraweb probably won't help much in decompressing .Z files, unless they are actually gzip-compressed files wrongly given the .Z file-name extension.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for sorting that out.

Comment: @philnext, I found the LZW Delphi implementation in [link](http://read.pudn.com/downloads118/sourcecode/delphi_control/499827/LZW.PAS__.htm)'LZW.pas'. Maybe this is a lightweight solution you need? BTW, you may need to register first to get access.

Comment: Another one is an old pascal implementation [link](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/2211/0/ZipView.aspx). Maybe you can use it with some modification.

Comment: @philnext, another one here [link](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid3E9DDF9CEB45214E1C006B3964F1C86560FB7770.aspx?s=lzw#L1)[/link]

Comment: @Hendra thanks for the links, but I would have a 'out of the box' library.

Comment: I use this and i think have z decompresion but no you can avoid the 7zip.dll ... [7zip api header from progdigy](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=13)

Comment: @azrael11, it uses the 7-zip dll (7z.dll) and OP wants to avoid the use of it.

Comment: Here is a Delphi implementation of Ian Hunters TP LZW compression/decompression library: [CompressLZW.pas](http://read.pudn.com/downloads95/sourcecode/others/385390/example/CustomCompressor/CompressLZW.pas__.htm). The original TP code can be found at [SWAG archives](http://swag.outpostbbs.net/ARCHIVES/0013.PAS.html).

Answer (score 1):

To decompress .Z files I simply use Delphi XE2's built in ZLib library:

```
uses ...,ZLib;

procedure UnpackFiles;
var
  LList: TStringDynArray;
  I: Integer;
  FileName: String;
  DestFileName: String;
  LUnZip: TZDecompressionStream;
  LInput, LOutput: TFileStream;
begin
  LList:= TDirectory.GetFiles(ImportDir, '*.gz');
  for i:= 0 to Length(LList)-1 do
  begin
    FileName:= LowerCase(LList[i]);
    DestFileName:= ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.csv');
    { Create the Input, Output, and Decompressed streams. }
    LInput := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmOpenRead);
    LOutput := TFileStream.Create(DestFileName, fmCreate);
    LUnZip := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LInput, 15+16); // 16 = read as gzip header !

    Log(Format('create uncompressed file %s', [DestFileName]));
    { Decompress data. }
    LOutput.CopyFrom(LUnZip, 0);

    { Free the streams. }
    LUnZip.Free;
    LInput.Free;
    LOutput.Free;
    Log(Format('Delete compressed file %s', [FileName]));
    DeleteFile(FileName);
  end;
end;
```

The important part is to set the option to read a gzip header:

```
LUnZip := TZDecompressionStream.Create(LInput, 15+16); // 16 = read as gzip header !
```

Comment: From documentation: `windowBits can also be greater than 15 for optional gzip decoding. Add 32 to windowBits to enable zlib and gzip decoding with automatic header detection, or add 16 to decode only the gzip format (the zlib  format will return a Z_DATA_ERROR). If a gzip stream is being decoded, strm->adler is a crc32 instead of an adler32.`