# How to use TDecompressionStream?

Tags: delphi, http, gzip, decode

I want to decompress a gzip data (a http message body), and I tried the following code, but it's not working, it rise an exception when I try to read from the stream. What is wrong ?

```
uses zlib;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var InStream: TStream;
    ZStream: TDecompressionStream;
    s:string;
    x:int64;
begin
 InStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;

 s:='...the gziped body here...';   //binary string
 InStream.Write(s[1],length(s));
 InStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);

 ZStream:=TDecompressionStream.Create(InStream);
 SetLength(s,10000);
 x:=ZStream.Read(s[1],10000);
 SetLength(s,x);

 Label1.Caption:=s;

 InStream.Free;
 ZStream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: yes, the program stops and shows me an error

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?  What is the error message?

Comment: Delphi 6, Project1.exe raised exception class ECompressionError with message 'error'.

Comment: @marusnebunu I meant that 'an' exception is not very helpful, as is 'an error'. Please provide details about the error you get. It might be helpful for yourself as well to read errors.

Comment: Just 'error'? Not 'file error' or 'buffer error' or 'data error'? That's not much. But ECompressionError at least is thrown by the decompression stream. So it's no access violation or other obvious error. Most likely the 'binary' string isn't a proper gzip sequence. Maybe you can read the data from a file instead?

Comment: Most likely your input is invalid. It troubles me that you use a string to represent binary data. If I can offer one piece of advice it is that gzip encodes binary to binary. It is not a text based algorithm.

Comment: I know, but strings can hold binary data as well.

Comment: Except for the 10000 limit, which you might overthink, and that you should use a try-finally-block, so that `Free` is always called, I have not seen any problem. I tried it myself and found out that if `s` does not contain correct binary gzip-data, zlib.pas will raise an `ECompressionError` exception with the message "error" (very detailled...). So it is most likely that the function which provided the binary string `s` (http message body) provided something wrong or maybe something was accidently appended at the end of the HTTP output (e.g. a warning from a server side PHP script).

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to decrypt the base 64 encoded data?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that my gzip data is not gzip data or is some version of gzip that zlib.pas do not recognise. I tried to compress and decompress with zlib.pas and it works fine. But my gzip data is a standar body of a http message with header `Content-Encoding: gzip` included.

Comment: My HTTP transfer encoding knowledge is a bit rusty... Do you have a gzip header or zlib header at the beginning?

Comment: If it is gzip, you have to allow header sensing more bits down the stream than default 15 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911347/delphi-xe2-z-unix-compressed-files-library#comment15946540_11964643

Comment: As noted in comments, this is "Indeed, it seems that my gzip data is not gzip data or is some version of gzip that zlib.pas do not recognise. I tried to compress and decompress with zlib.pas and it works fine. But my gzip data is a standar body of a http message with header Content-Encoding: gzip included". Clearly a bad question

Comment: No, strings hold text. Don't make the mistake that so many people do of putting binary data into strings.

Comment: @KromStern, zlib won't recognize anything other than its own format by default.

Comment: @FreeConsulting I don't know what's in the gziped body, I only know that it's a gzip stream because that tells me the header 'Content-Encoding: gzip' of the response message.

Comment: @marusnebunu, examine and figure out then... As suggested already this data might be erroneous.

Answer (score 2):

> It raises an exception when I try to read from the stream. What is wrong?

The most plausible explanation is that you are not passed valid GZIP encoded data to the stream. It's impossible for us to say why your data would be invalid because we don't know its provenance. To solve your problem you must first of all work out why your data is invalid.

One obvious issue with your code is the use of a string to represent binary data. GZIP operates on binary data. It compresses byte arrays to byte arrays. To work with text you use a predetermined encoding to convert text to binary. Once compressed, you would use something like MIME or base64 to encode the compressed binary as text. Perhaps your data is of this form: binary encoded as text.

Another possible issue is that your Delphi `zlib` unit is deficient, or simply out-dated. You don't state in the question which version of Delphi you use. Perhaps you are using an old version of Delphi that does not ship with a `zlib` unit and are using a third party `zlib` unit that is no good.

Comment: I researched and found that my (http body) gzip data passed to zlib `TDecompressionStream` is valid. [Check this image](http://s8.postimg.org/l9xqszcxx/gzip.jpg). It has the same body with the data copressed by zlib plus the standard header and trailer. If I try to decompress my http body data with Winrar it works fine. I've tried to pass to `TDecompressionStream` the data without header and trailer but it still rise the exception. The only way it works is with the data in the third format (compressed by zlib). It needs those misterious bytes at the begining and the end of the copressed block.

Comment: Do you expect anything more than this answer. Look closely at the question you asked and the information you provided.

Comment: Anyway, if your code succeeds with data that you compress, and fails with the other data you have, doesn't that indicate that your other data is not in the correct form?

Comment: No, it indicate that zlib.pas has it's own compression format and it's not standard gzip. I found a new unit (possible a new version of zlib.pas, I don't know exactly) named [ZLibExGZ](http://www.base2ti.com/?id=delphi.zlib) which has a function `GZDecompressStr()` that decompress a standard gzip http body correctly. And it works with binary strings, exactly what I was looking for ! :)

Comment: No. The zlib units that ship with Delphi are Pascal wrappers around the standard official zlib code, compiled and linked as static .obj files. And there's no such thing as a binary string. There's not much point in us continuing this conversation since we quite clearly disagree with each other.

Comment: Of course, we don't even know which zlib you are using.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, [QC125018 System.ZLIB implementaion has a bug in ZDecompressCheck function](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125018).